# Corrupt C runtime library?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, msvcrt, microsoft-runtime-library

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012 (with Update 2) and since I have a project that needs to be built with the VC++ 2010 toolset I also installed Visual C++ 2010 Express (with SP1).

I use the newer 2012 IDE also for the older projects. So for these projects I set the Platform Toolset to v100. And when I also set the runtime library to /MT or /MTd I get the following error:

```
error LNK1127: library is corrupt
```

for `libcpmt.lib` or `libcpmtd.lib`, depending on the configuration.

What could be wrong here?

Installation history:

1. VS2012 Professional
2. Windows 7 SDK
3. Uninstalled VS2012 and Windows SDK
4. VC++ 2010 Express
5. VS2012 Professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you installed VS2010 *after* installing VS2012? If not, please edit your question to make it clear.

This sequence of installations [is not recommended by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), and there are plenty of caveats and ReadMe's to navigate in order to find out what's happened.

I suggest that the best thing to do is to reinstall VS2012 (or do a repair install), then see what - if anything - is still broken.

Comment: Sorry this was not clear in my question. The installation history is a little bit longer. I installed VS2012 and then the Windows 7 SDK. That didn't work so I uninstalled both. Then I installed first VC++2010 Express with SP1 and then (again) VS2012 with the updates.

Comment: @RobertHegner - ok, and assuming there's no real disk error, you maybe need to install the Windows 7 SDK for the VS2010 toolset and make sure you run the Visual Studio Registration tool afterwards because VS2012 will have upset it.

Comment: A repair install of VC++2010 Express solved the problem. Thanks for your inputs!